# Can I use "than" without comparative adjectives or adverbs?

Tags: comparisons

I'm wondering whether I can use "than" without comparative adjectives or adverbs like the following sentence:

They actually benefit from not having pets than having them.

It sounds right to me. But I cannot confirm that it's correct. I've tried to search for the answers in the net and some grammar books, but have been unsuccessful.

Chirapat

Comment: No. In Britain, at least, it is not idiomatic. However Americans do have a way of using "than" such as in "different than" e.g. *chalk is different than cheese*, whilst in Britain we would say *chalk is different to cheese*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't spot the omission of "more". You need "They actually benefit more from not having pets than having them."  "Having them" is a comparative clause as complement of "than", where "them" is anaphoric to "pets".

Comment: It is better to give than to receive.

Comment: Thank you very much. So it seems that I cannot omit comparative adjectives or adverbs when using than in comparison.
But in this I like to compare them in the sense of “better” not “more”. However, if I write this sentence as “They actually benefit better from not having pets than having them.”. Does it sound right? 
Or I should put it another way such as “It’s better for them not to have pets than to have pets.”.
Are the two statements grammatically correct? Is one of them preferable to the other?
Chirapat

Comment: 287279, please notice that you seem to be taking what went before, twisting it and building something different on the remains.

Could you go back to "I like to compare…" and post a separate Question without that distortion?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. But I’m sorry; I don’t quite understand what you’re talking about. I was just wondering whether I could construct a sentence using “than” without using comparative adjectives or adverbs. Now, from the comments from WS2 and Nigel J, I understand that I can’t. And the sentence has to be “They actually benefit better/more from not having pets than having them.”. I was just wondering a bit more whether this last sentence and the sentence “It’s better for them not to have pets than to have pets.” are grammatically correct or which one of them is preferable to the other.